# JMeter HTML report: Display all failed transaction are passed in HTML report

Tags: jmeter

After execution of test plan, generated HTML report from .jtl file and in HTML report request summary displayed as all passed where 2 transactions are failed. Getting 100% error in Statistics table of same report.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Screenshots of request summary and Statistics:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The report seems to be corrupted. As on the top header total sample display ran as "5" while there are more in the list. Also KO is displayed zero on top. Can you try to generate the HTML report in any empty folder again using the **new** JTL.

Answer (score 0):

For me this [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles):

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1588246500533,135,jp@gc - Dummy Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,114,0,1,1,null,34,0,3
1588246500672,413,jp@gc - Dummy Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,false,,114,0,1,1,null,20,0,3
```

results into correct APPDEX table in the HTML Reporting Dashboard:

[image]

You can try generating the dashboard from above 3-lines .jtl file and if you see the same result - it means that your .jtl file is broken or somehow not usable by current JMeter setup.

You can validate the consistency of the .jtl results file by opening it in i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener:

[image]

or generate equivalent CSV representation using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv aggregatereport.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

[image]

if you get incorrect results - you will need to reconsider the way of generating the .jtl results file or inspect [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

If the .jtl file is fine but dashboard output is weird most probably it's the result of improper customization in one of the following places:

- [jmeter.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/jmeter.properties) file
- [user.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/user.properties) file
- [reportgenerator.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/reportgenerator.properties) file
- [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.2.1/bin/report-template) folder